# consulta webbrowser c#

Tags: c#, navegador-web

tengo una duda si esto se puede plantear así porque me está leyendo la misma url envés de las que figuran en la lista, no se si tengo que destruir el objeto "navegador" o como seria?? soy nuevo usando esto

```
  for (int i=0;i<listView1.Items.Count;i++)
        {

           string nombrepj= listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text;
           string url_Completa = url_base + nombrepj;

            navegador.Navigate(url_Completa);
            navegador.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true; //oculta los errores de script
            navegador.DocumentCompleted += datos_cargados;

        }
```

Comment: a que te referis con que lee la misma url.. no esta navegando a la que le pasas por la variable? puede que solo lea la ultima? o la primera? me parece que ese for va montones de veces mas rapido, que lo que el navegar tarda en leer una url.

Comment: claro, cuando le pasa los datos cargados al leer todo el documento me esta mostrando los mismo datos del ultimo en leer

Comment: y si.. no le das tiempo a todos los otros a que carguen.. esto no deberia estar codificado asi.. si no con un proceso que le pida que navegue, y que espere (y este es el punto importante) la respuesta. vos lo estas codificando como si al llamar a una pagina la respuesta fuera directa. y no funciona de esa forma internet. siempre tenes que esperar algo.

Comment: como podría verificar eso entonces??

Comment: Ese es justamente, tu trabajo ;). documentcompleted es el evento que se ejecuta cuando termina de cargar no? pues por ahi tiene que venir la solucion.

Comment: claro por eso cargo los datos capturando ese evento

Comment: no. no los cargas ahi.. porque por cada vuelta, le decis que vaya a otra pagina.. pero la anterior no termino de cargar.. esta mal la logica de tu proceso.